# WebDriverWait in Chrome, Selenium C#

Tags: c#, selenium, automation, webdriver, selenium-chromedriver

I have recently changed my WebDriver from Firefox to ChromeDriver and the wait steps I previously used to wait until an element could be interacted with no longer works"

`WebDriverWait w = new WebDriverWait(driver, TimeSpan.FromSeconds(10));
        w.IgnoreExceptionTypes(typeof(StaleElementReferenceException), typeof(InvalidElementStateException));
        w.Until(ExpectedConditions.ElementExists(By.Id("formSubmit")));`

I now often get errors like "Element is not clickable at point (964, 776). Other element would receive the click: " for example, even though the element is visible on the page.

Is there a way of telling the webdriver to wait until an element can be interacted with, or better, any settings that I could change to let Selenium know that I'm using Chrome so that my existing code works?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Latest version of [Selenium C# Binding(2.46)](http://seleniumhq.github.io/selenium/docs/api/dotnet/index.html) provides a method to Expected Conditions named `ElementToBeClickable`. Try that instead. This is a very common issue with Chrome though.

Comment: Thanks, I have moved to 2.46 and it looks like that has worked. Thanks very much.

Answer (score 0):

There is more than one way.

This is my favourite:

```
try {
   // For example
   site.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_drp_City")).Click();

}
catch {
    Thread.Sleep(/* <Time in seconds> */);

    site.FindElement(By.Id("ctl00_ContentPlaceHolderBody_drp_City")).Click();
}
```

Comment: Using sleep() vs. WebDriverWait seems at odds. The question was *"Is there a way of telling the webdriver to wait until an element can be interacted with?"*